# How to speed up my games fps?

Tags: java, performance

I have my game which, on every render loop, loops through all the blocks in my map (128x128) which as you can probably tell, causes a lot of lag. When I first made it, I had to make it render only the blocks on the screen, or it would crash instantly. Now I only render the blocks on the screen, but still loop through all the blocks to see if they are on the screen, which makes my fps about 2.

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
            Block b = LevelGen.getBlockAt(x, y);
            if (Forgotten.isInsideGameWindow(x * 30, y * 30)) {
                arg1.drawImage(b.getTexture(), x * 30, y * 30);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it so doesn't loop through all of them?

Comment: Are the textures/images preloaded? Or are you loading an image each time it is drawing the image?

Comment: How does `Forgotten` know if the coordinates you provide are "inside the game window?" (e.g. what does `Forgotten.isInsideGameWindow` do?)  If it's comparing the `x` and `y` you provide to some other `x` and `y`, then an't you just draw the image at that other `x` and `y` and avoid the loops altogether?

Comment: Can you scroll the original graphics so you only have to re-draw the edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figure out the size of your display window, and only iterate blocks that are within it.

```
final int tile_size = 30;

final RectangleType displayWindow = Forgotten.getDisplayWindow ();

final int left = displayWindow.getLeft () / tile_size - 1;
final int right = displayWindow.getRight () / tile_size + 1;
final int top = displayWindow.getTop () / tile_size - 1;
final int bottom = displayWindow.getBottom () / tile_size + 1;

for (int y = top; y < bottom; ++y)
   for (int x = left; x < right; ++x)
       canvas.drawImage (LevelGen.getBlockAt (x,y).getTexture (),
                         x * tile_size, y * tile_size);
```

You may also want to figure out which area(s) of the canvas actually want to be drawn, and instead keep a "dirty rectangle" list of areas to be redrawn. Whenever a tile changes, or a sprite/particle/whatever passes through its space, add that tile to the rectangle. Even if you just use a single dirty rectangle that enlarges to encompass all updates during a frame, if your game doesn't actually have "stuff happening" at all points on the display at all times, your frame rate will be higher on average (but suffer from large-scale effects)

**expanding upon that:**

```
      public class Map {
            private Rectangle dirtyRect = null;

            public void dirty (Rectangle areaAffected) {
                   if (null == dirtyRect) {
                        dirtyRect = areaAffected; return;
                   }
                   dirtyRect = new Rectangle ( Math.min (dirtyRect.getLeft (),
                                                         areaAffected.getLeft () ),
                                               Math.min (dirtyRect.getTop (),
                                                         areaAffected.getTop () ),
                                               Math.max (dirtyRect.getRight (),
                                                         areaAffected.getRight () ),
                                               Math.max (dirtyRect.getBottom (),
                                                         areaAffected.getBottom () ));
            }
```

Then use the dirty rectangle in place of `displayWindow` for normal draws, and you can test `if (null == getDirtyRectangle ()) return;` to skip drawing at all if nothing's changed.

Comment: BTW you can increment x+=tile_size and y+=tile_size instead x++ or y++

Comment: You can't, because x and y use tiles as units, where tile_size would most likely use pixels? You could do the whole coordinates in pixels, but then you'd have to use division to get the block's coordinates in tiles.

Comment: I skipped on that bit due to `.getBlockAt`; however, a hybrid approach would probably be best if worried about the multiplication by a `final int`; `for (int y = top, yPixel = top * tile_size; y < bottom; ++y, yPixel += tile_size) … getBlockAt (x,y).getTexture (), xPixel, yPixel … `

Comment: and, not that it probably deeply matters, but keep in mind that multiplies are typically much slower than adds, but divides are typically *waaaaay* slower than multiplies… and I'm going to presume that drawing a tile costs many times either of these :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could just insert a break inside of your code block.. but then I don't see the purpose of this code looking through 16, 32, or 256 times...

Comment: You could pre-determine which blocks will be on screen then make the for loops start and stop accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could place all the blocks in an array, include coordinates in the block object then  use those to draw the block. Then you'd only have to loop through the blocks that appear on screen. Only useful if there aren't that many blocks on screen though.